# How to retrieve subclass entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I created following entities structure:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SingleChange {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class SingleChangeByFoot extends SingleChange{

    Double lengthInMinutes;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class SingleChangeByVehicle extends SingleChange{

    String lineName;
    String firstStop;
    String lastStop;
}
```

I also created JPA repositories for each entity.

And I would like to ask how to retrieve subclasses when I only have id using JPA repository. I tried getting objects using SingleChangeRepository and then using `getClass()` method or `instanceof` operator but it returns something like SingleChange behind Hibernate proxy, it doesn't say whether this object is of class SingleChangeByFoot or SingleChangeByVehicle. How do I know whether I should use SingleChangeByFoot repository or SingleChangeByVehicleRepository

Comment: You must declare your main class as `abstract`. `public abstract class SingleChange {` and then the `.getClass()` will work

Comment: It didn't work but thanks to your answer I was able to find a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093466/hibernate-inheritance-getting-superclass-instance-and-casting-into-subclass